# Error while adding application_name as a parameter in dask.read_sql_table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, dask

I am trying to create a dask dataframe from a table in postgres. 
I would like to pass the **application_name = 'myapp'** as a standard 
for monitoring and tracking DB activity.

But when am trying to add the parameter, I getting below error.

```
ddf = dd.read_sql_table('table', 
                        uri, 
                        schema='schema', 
                        index_col='index_col', 
                        engine_kwargs={'application_name':'myapp'})
```

> TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'application_name' sent to
>   create_engine(), using configuration
>   PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword
>   arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

Comment: To which function is `application_name` a valid input, where do you expect this to go?

Comment: I am expecting SQLAlchemy to use it while creating engine.

Comment: The exception suggests `create_engine()` does not want this keyword. Can you create a sqalchemy engine independently?

Comment: I refered :[issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2975) and updated code as engine_kwargs={'connect_args': {'application_name':'myapp'}. Now its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the correct syntax was

```
ddf = dd.read_sql_table('table', 
                        uri, 
                        schema='schema', 
                        index_col='index_col', 
                        engine_kwargs={'connect_args': {'application_name': 'myapp'})
```

since the call to make the sqlalchemy engine looks like

```
engine = create_engine(uri, connect_kwargs={'application_name':' myapp'})
```

Comment: engine = create_engine(uri, connect_args={'application_name':' myapp'})
connect_kwargs in the answer above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- ***PostgreSQL Database :***

The following works in `sqlalchemy==1.3.10`

```
    # Establish database connection via sqlalchemy

    sqlalchemy_connection_kwargs = {'connect_args': {'application_name': 'herles_application'}}

    connection = create_engine(sqlalchemy_connection_string, **sqlalchemy_connection_kwargs)
```

If you are using `psycopg2-binary==2.8.4` native connection

```
native_connection = psycopg2.connect(user=cred['username'],
                                     password=cred['password'],
                                     host=cred['host'],
                                     port=cred['port'],
                                     database=cred['databaseName'],
                                     application_name="herles_application")
```